# Getting started with sessions

Tags: spring, spring-session

I am using Spring-MVC to build a website prototype. We have a MySQL database that we address using Hibernate.

Now, I want to add basic user session handling (user can login, do stuff on the site and logout). I thought it should be easy to do, but after a bit of research I feel a bit lost.

I have seen the spring-session project. It seems it depends on a redis server for storing session data. Is there a way I could use my existing Mysql/Hibernate setup for storing the session data?

Also, what is the most easiest way to do sesions in spring-mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions will be maintained within the web/app servers like Tomcat, Weblogic etc., you need not to store session related stuff in any database.

Comment: may he need because when app prevent to multi login at same time then need to store session related stuff in db as per my view

Comment: ok, such information can easily be stored in MySQL DB which is being used in the application. I do not think there is any need for different data store.